# Xcode Use of undeclared identifier 'func'

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I keep getting the same error

> Use of undeclared identifier 'GetTextSize'

Here's my code :

```c++
Vector2D nameSize = GetTextSize(string, testfont); // This is where I get the error
```

```c++
Vector2D GetTextSize(const char* text, HFONT font)
{
    std::wstring wc = StringToWstring(text);

    int x_res, y_res;
    GetTextSize(font, wc.c_str(), x_res, y_res); 
    // ^^^ This is a different func with the same name
    return Vector2D(x_res, y_res);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define/declare `GetTextSize()` **before** using it.

In other word, make sure that defination/declaration of `GetTextSize()` is before the calling.

That comes two solutions:

```
// Define the function first
Vector2D GetTextSize(const char* text, HFONT font)
{
    std::wstring wc = StringToWstring(text);

    int x_res, y_res;
    GetTextSize(font, wc.c_str(), x_res, y_res); 
    // ^^^ This is a different func with the same name
    return Vector2D(x_res, y_res);
}

// Then you can use it
Vector2D nameSize = GetTextSize(string, testfont);
```

Or:

```
// Declare the function first
Vector2D GetTextSize(const char* text, HFONT font);

// Then you can use it
Vector2D nameSize = GetTextSize(string, testfont); // This is where I get the error

// Defination of the function
Vector2D GetTextSize(const char* text, HFONT font)
{
    std::wstring wc = StringToWstring(text);

    int x_res, y_res;
    GetTextSize(font, wc.c_str(), x_res, y_res); 
    // ^^^ This is a different func with the same name
    return Vector2D(x_res, y_res);
}
```